# List elements to equal zero after 0 element

Tags: python, list

suppose I have a list

```
 l = [4,3,3,2,1,0,1,2]
```

How can I make every element after the 0, be equal to zero? So I want the list to read

```
l = [4,3,3,2,1,0,0,0]
```

Comment: THANKS ALL! Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add another options to all these good answers, another one with lambda:

```
l = [4,3,3,2,1,0,1,2]
f= lambda x,i : 0 if 0 in x[:i] else x[i]
[f(l,i) for i in range(len(l))]
```

output:

```
[4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Good solution! Many ways to skin a cat :-)

Answer (score 5):

`l[:l.index(0)] + [0]*(len(l)-l.index(0))`

The first part keeps the list the same until the element that contains 0. The second part repeats 0 the required number of times.

Answer (score 3):

I would check that 0 actually exists in the list first:

```
lst = [4,3,3,2,1,0,0,0]

try: 
    idx = lst.index(0) 
    lst[idx:] = [0] * (len(lst) - idx) 
except ValueError: 
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Using brute force approach

```
l = [4,3,3,2,1,0,1,2]
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == 0:
        for j in range(i, len(l)):
            l[j] = 0
        break   #to break the for-i loop
print(l)
```

Output `[4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]`